# NullPointerException with adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this observer for my viewmodel so that I can setup my adapter but, when I run the app, it gives me the NullPointerException error on this line:

```
japaneseAdapter = it.data?.let { it1 -> JapaneseAdapter(it1) }!!
```

This is the activity with that line:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class JapaneseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var binding: ActivityJapaneseBinding
   private val japaneseViewModel by viewModels<JapaneseViewModel>()
   private lateinit var japaneseAdapter: JapaneseAdapter

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       binding = ActivityJapaneseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)

       japaneseViewModel.japaneseResponse.observe(this, {
           when(it.status){
               Resource.Status.LOADING -> { }
               Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                   japaneseAdapter = it.data?.let { it1 -> JapaneseAdapter(it1) }!!
                   binding.rvNews.adapter = japaneseAdapter
               }
               Resource.Status.ERROR -> { Log.d("ERROR","ERROR RAISED") }
           }
       })
   }
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
class JapaneseAdapter(private var japaneseResponse: List<JapaneseResponse>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<JapaneseAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(
        view: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val binding = NewsItemsBinding.bind(view)

        private val itemTitle: TextView = binding.tvTitle
        private val itemImage: ImageView = binding.ivNews
        private val itemDescription: TextView = binding.tvDescription

        fun bind(response: JapaneseResponse) {
            Picasso.get().load(response.urlToImage).into(itemImage)
            itemTitle.text = response.Title
            itemDescription.text = response.Description
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(japaneseResponse[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return japaneseResponse.size
    }

}
```

Generic data source:

```
abstract class BaseDataSource {

    protected suspend fun <T> getResult(call: suspend () -> Response<ApiResponse<T>>): Resource<T> {
        try {
            val response = call()
//            if(response.isSuccessful) {
//                val body = response.body()?.data
//                if(body != null) return Resource.success(body)
//            }
            val body = response.body()?.data
            return Resource.success(body)
            //return Resource.error("${response.code()}: ${response.message()}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Resource.error(e.message ?: "Generic error")
        }
    }
}

data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) : Serializable {

    enum class Status {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        LOADING
    }

    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(
                Status.SUCCESS,
                data,
                null
            )
        }

        fun <T> error(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(
                Status.ERROR,
                data,
                message
            )
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T? = null): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(
                Status.LOADING,
                data,
                null
            )
        }
    }

    fun isSuccessful() = status == Status.SUCCESS

    fun isError() = status == Status.ERROR

    fun isLoading() = status == Status.LOADING
}
```

The data source for the Japanese news:

```
class JapaneseDataSource @Inject constructor(private val japaneseService: JapaneseService) :
    BaseDataSource() {

    suspend fun getJpNews() = getResult { japaneseService.jpNews() }
}
```

Repository:

```
class JapaneseRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val remote: JapaneseDataSource
) {
    suspend fun jpNews() =
        remote.getJpNews()
}
```

The service:

```
interface JapaneseService {
    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?country=jp&apiKey=77acc490875643c5b2328fb615e0cf83")
    suspend fun jpNews(): Response<ApiResponse<List<JapaneseResponse>>>
}
```

I can see that the response is there since I have okhttp logging it for me but for some reason it seems to be null and I am not sure why...
Any help?

Comment: It's still a duplicate, there's an extensive canned answer ...and there is no debug info at all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: It is very possible that I should have left it alone. I don't think that `NullPointerException` lends itself to a canned answer, since the exception has a zillion possible causes. Usually, I *do* leave it alone; I rarely vote to reopen. This time, I was 80% of the way through typing in an answer that would more directly help this developer when it was closed, so I peevishly voted to reopen. I forgot that in this case it would go all the way open (I expected it to just count as a vote). But, given that, I wrapped up my answer. I apologize if you took offense at my actions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've indeed looked for a more Kotln-specific dupe... and null-ness is being handled slightly different, but in the end - it still produces a Java NPE. I'd rather suggest to [debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) and to read the corresponding [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```kotlin
japaneseAdapter = it.data?.let { it1 -> JapaneseAdapter(it1) }!!
```

`!!` is Kotlin's "crash the app" operator. It says that you want to crash the app if the value you are applying `!!` to is `null`. Your objective, as a Kotlin programmer, is to avoid using `!!`.

In this case, the fact that you are crashing on that line with that error means that `!!` is being applied to `null`. That will occur if `it.data` evaluates to `null`.

`it.data` appears to be a `Resource` object with a `status` of `SUCCESS`. So, presumably, you are calling `success()` with a value of `null`.

With all that in mind, you will need to use your debugger and see why `val body = response.body()?.data` is evaluating to `null`, or see where else you are getting a `Resource` with `null` data.

And, please, try to avoid using `!!`.

Comment: okay that's a good advice, thank you